# ->after() on Laravel artisan Schedule Command with closure is a string?

Tags: php, lambda, closures, laravel-5.1, anonymous-function

```
$slackNotify = function() use (&$info) { ... };
$schedule->command('Calc:RPI 1 2015')->cron('0 */2 * 8-12 *')
    ->withoutOverlapping()->sendOutputTo($this->path . 'rpi.html')
    ->after($slackNotify('My message here'));
```

> Error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event::after() must be an instance of Closure, string given, ...

Why does it think `$slackNotify(...)` is a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I'm using a lambda and not an anonymous function (which is *NEARLY* the same thing, but still not).

The `->after()` command expects an anonymous function, so I just needed to add that in and pass my lambda into it:

WAS / Lambda:

```
->after($slackNotify('My Message Here'));
```

IS / anonymous:

```
->after(function() use ($slackNotify) {$slackNotify('My Message Here');});
```

Thanks to [rizqi](https://larachat.slack.com/team/rizqi) for the help in explaining what I really was doing.